# Help with the word "resist"!

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

Is this grammatically right?

> I can't resist feeling life changing.
>   I can't resist being sad.
>   I can't resist being proud.

Can I say it like that or is there another way?

Comment: Yes, the constructions are grammatical. Do have any reason why you think they are ungrammatical?

Comment: The first sentence isn't idiomatic to me. Typically "life changing" describes something that changed the direction of your life, for example a "life-changing event". If you feel life changing, you feel like you are that force that changes other people's lives. For example, "I helped ten kids get accepted into good schools and I can't resist feeling life-changing." I would say "I can't resist feeling like/that life is changing."

Answer (score 1):

The word *'resist'* here means *'to withstand the action or effect of.'*

All the three sentences are grammatically correct.

> - I can't resist feeling life changing.
> - I can't resist being sad.
> - I can't resist being proud.

Answer (score 1):

Well, some of them are good, some of them not so much, for example:

> I can't resist feeling life changing

Is unclear. Can you not resist the inevitable changes that come with time as you go through life, or can you not resist *feeling* as thought your life is changing? That sentence is confusing, and I'm not sure what you're implying. Did you mean to say:

> I can't stop life from changing

or

> I can't help but feel as though my life is changing.

As for the rest

> I can't resist being proud
>
> I can't resist being sad

are at least clear in their meaning, but don't sound quite natural, as "resisting" feelings isn't something people do that much. They resist *expressing* feelings more often than they resist the feeling itself. It is a bit strange to say you "resist being" because "being" is a binary state. Either you are or you are not. Resistance implies some intermediary. If you are even *a little sad* it is fair to say that you are *feeling sad*.

So if you mean to say, that you do feel proud, even though you know you shouldn't be, you might say

> I can't help but feel proud.

If you mean to illustrate the struggle against the feeling, for example of sadness, you might say

> I can't stop feeling sad, no matter how hard I try.

Answer (score -1):

All your sentences are correct!

From my view, I can rewrite your sentence to:

> I can't resist feeling life changing. → I feel frustrated at the change of life.
>   I can't resist being sad. → I can't resist my sadness.
>   I can't resist being proud. → I can't resist having self-respect.

Give me your comments, if there're problems in my grammar! Thank you so much.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Your answer doesn't answer OP's question. Consider pointing to why exactly you rephrased his sentences and do you consider his variants correct or not. Please leave out the introductory part in your answer!